# How to get a token pair's uniswap trade history?

Tags: javascript, uniswap

What I am trying to do is this :-

Given an pair (say DAI/ETH pair), i want to display the latest 10-15 trades (buy, sell, add to pool and remove from pool) and also display a graph of price for that pair.

How can i get the relevent data using uniswap js sdk/api?

Comment: love your nick name =-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the Uniswap TheGraph for this! For example a query to get the last 10 swaps from the DAI/ETH pair would be:

```
{
    swaps(first: 10, where: { pair: "0xa478c2975ab1ea89e8196811f51a7b7ade33eb11" } orderBy: timestamp, orderDirection: desc) {
      transaction {
        id
        timestamp
      }
      id
      pair {
        token0 {
          id
          symbol
        }
        token1 {
          id
          symbol
        }
      }
      amount0In
      amount0Out
      amount1In
      amount1Out
      amountUSD
      to
    }
}
```

You can play around with queries at: https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2. Integration into the frontend would happen with something like [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).

In fact this is also what the [Uniswap Info](https://uniswap.info/) is doing. It's [open-source](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-info), so look around for [example queries](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-info/blob/a8251098654d7ea0e1b7f036813d61b6c4ff20cf/src/apollo/queries.js) and [how to use them](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-info/blob/004c7d525078fe0d2518255d77581318525e696b/src/contexts/TokenData.js#L486).

For more information on how TheGraph and queries work, I just posted a blog-post about it: https://soliditydeveloper.com/thegraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check them all. You are a life saver.

Comment: Is it possible to get the marginal price (eg. the price after the trade)?

Comment: @wanheda What exactly do you want to achieve? You can use time-travel queries with TheGraph, see https://thegraph.com/docs/graphql-api#queries under time-travel. But there's also built-in oracle functionality: https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/core-concepts/oracles/.

Comment: @Markus-soliditydeveloper.com praise to you! The time-travel functionality was what I needed (to get the pair statistics at the block of the trade). Note that it still won't be exact as there can be many trades within a block, making the price (and even the constant) deviate.

Comment: Hi @markus, I'm fairly new to the graph search for uniswap. So, sorry for sounding like a noob. But, Can you guide me how could we find the token pair address programatically? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ayushnarula that is indeed possible, see https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses/

Comment: Is there a way to include how much gas was paid per transaction in the query

Comment: @johnny5 It seems that its not included inside the transaction element of swap, you can see it in the schema. But it's theoretically possible to add: https://thegraph.com/docs/developer/assemblyscript-api#events-and-blocktransaction-data

Comment: @Markus-soliditydeveloper.com Is it possible to define a timestamp interval?

Comment: @Payam Yes that should be possible if you use where: transaction.timestamp_gt: minTimestamp and transaction.timestamp_lt: maxTimestamp. But this syntax is completely wrong, you would have to look up the correct syntax.