# How to get the history of adding & removing liquidity of a certain Uniswap pool?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

Swap history of a pool can be easily retrieved using theGraph like this:
[How to get a token pair's uniswap trade history?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/how-to-get-a-token-pairs-uniswap-trade-history)

But is it possible to get the history of adding & removing liquidity of a certain Uniswap pool? It may be difficult to realized using theGraph. But is there any Dex statistic website can help?

Comment: UniswapV2Pair contract inherits ERC20 token interface, this token isused to count shares of liquidity each contributor provides. burn/mint events will tell you who added/removed liquidity. So you need to process all mint/burn/transfer events on this token (the UniswapPair contract)

Comment: the source code is your friend https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol