# How to get a token pair's entire uniswap trade history?

Tags: uniswap, python

I'm trying to query the *entire* transaction history of a given pair (e.g. WETH/USDT). Hence, this question is similar to [How to get a token pair's uniswap trade history?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/how-to-get-a-token-pairs-uniswap-trade-history)

My approach is to use the GraphQL Python client and iterate through the transactions using the `skip` keyword. In the example below, I'd increment skip by 1000 for every iteration.

```
query {
            swaps(first: 1000, skip: ''' + str(x) + ''', where: {pair: "0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852"} orderBy: timestamp, orderDirection: desc) {
                    transaction {
                        id
                        timestamp
                    }
                    id
                    pair {
                        token0 {
                            id
                            symbol
                        }
                        token1 {    
                            id
                            symbol
                        }
                }
                amount0In
                amount1In
                amount0Out
                amount1Out
                amountUSD
                to
            }
            }
```

Sadly, this only works for values from 0 to 5000. Does anyone know how to circumvent this issue or knows another way to get the entire transaction history?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ready solution to offer you, but I can shine some light on the matter. Solutions like TheGraph are amazing for lighter tasks, like getting a few thousand events. But in order to work with larger datasets, it's usually not sufficient.

So in order to get all history of a specific pair on Uniswap, you would have to have access to an Ethereum full node (either your own or someone else's), and go through each block looking for the `Swap` event. Then you would need t o build up a database with these events, which you then can query similarly to what you are doing with TheGraph.

I'm working hard on rolling out this functionality through a simple API through Moralis, where I work. But we need a few more weeks.